# Typescript accept intellisense selection on space or continuing typing

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, typescript, intellisense

Currently in Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> to accept the selected intellisense item.

I am more used to pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> or continuing to type when working in C#. Is there a way to enable such a feature while editing Typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify this behaviour using Resharper.

[image: Symbol completion]